# ComboBox formatting

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I know this is probably a stupidly easy question to answer but I'm going to ask it anyways.

So I have a combobox that when it's got data in it looks like this

[image]

I want to know if there is any way to make the data look like this instead while still using only 1 combobox

John, Doe

Nickel, Back

etc...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your code? It's look like you add datasource where Name and LastName is different items, you need to  connect it before set as datasource.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class for `Person` with first name and last name, then override `ToString()` method to output the string as you need.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + ", " + LastName;
    }
}
```

Now, you can create a list of people and bind to `DataSource` of comboBox.

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "Nickel", LastName = "Back" }
};
comboBox1.DataSource = people;
```